# Interactive report save

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When we create Interactive report and save it after deletion of Interactive Grid or page are reports saved somewhere or deleted forever.

I dont know if Oracle Apex saves reports after interactive grid is deleted,or Oracle Apex saves them somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe everything gets deleted.

For example, imagine it was page 1 which contained that interactive report (IR). You put some items onto it as well (so that you could filter data presented by the IR). You saved the page, used it for a while and then decided to delete it.

Once you're done, page number 1 is "free" to use and you *can* create a new page 1 - saving it, Apex won't say that "page 1 already exists" (somewhere). You can also name new items on page 1 with the same name as items on deleted page - no problem either.

Therefore, yes - I'd say that "Permanently delete" really means what it says.

[image]

Comment: Yes but do you maybe know if Interactve reports stay saved somewhere if only Interactive Grid is deleted.

Comment: I first thought that you accidentally mixed "report" and "grid" in the same question; apparently, you're not. What are you saying? That the same page contains both interactive report and interactive grid? Then you delete interactive grid region, but interactive report region stays as it was. If that's so, then yes - interactive report still exists (obviously), but ... that's just TOO OBVIOUS so I guess you're trying to ask something else. Could you explain it some more details?

Comment: When i save report in IG by using actions after that if i delete IG can i still somehow access those reports and if so how is that done?

Comment: Aha, *that* report! Nope, you can't access that/these reports. What you save through the "Actions" button is a) default report setting (if you're developer), or b) users' own report settings (they remove some columns, perform calculations, highlighting etc.). But, if interactive grid itself is removed, there's no definition which is the "base" of all these saved reports. So, no - don't remove interactive grid if you still need to use these reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an irreversible change to an app (eg delete a page, delete a region, remove a save IG or IR report then you can check if that still exists in a backup. By default apex creates backups at regular intervals. Restore a backup (from before you deleted your report) in a new app and look for the report that you have deleted. You will not be able to copy the report over from one app to another, but at least you'll be able to check the report in the old app and create it again manually.

[image]

Comment: I have one more question. How can I ensure that when importing a page from another application into my old one, all the existing reports created by the user remain? The issue arises when importing a new page into the old application, as the existing reports must be preserved. Could you explain the steps I need to take to achieve this?Default and private IG reports.

Comment: There are a couple of blogs about that, just google "apex export saved reports". I have not done this myself

Comment: You could also approach it the other way. Use the backup as your new main app and port over the changes you made since the backup manually. That way you will still have your saved reports. Up to you to decide what is the easiest. Usually it's not that hard to "re-do" stuff that you did recently